# Nav2d call getmap service failed

Tags: navigation, mapping, service, gmapping, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I already asked a question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/206344/nav2d_karto-mapper-doesnt-build-a-map/). I received no answer but I found a way to work around the problem. I'm currently still trying to use the exploration service provided by nav2d. I solved my problem of map building by changing the mapper node by the gmapping one.
But now I'm still not able to call the StartMapping and StartExplore services. I got this message: "Could not get a map."
I looked at the code to find the not respected condition and I found that:

```
ros::ServiceClient mGetMapClient = robotNode.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetMap>(std::string("get_map"));
nav_msgs::GetMap srv;
if(!mGetMapClient.call(srv))
{
ROS_INFO("Could not get a map.");
return false;
}
```

Have you any idea of what to do when a service doesn't work? And particularly this one?

Thank you in advance for any answer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207001/nav2d-call-getmap-service-failed/) by [Furane](https://answers.ros.org/users/22040/furane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked whether the service names match? Gmapping names the service "dynamic_map", while the Navigator defaults to "get_map". You can use the Navigator's "map_service" parameter to tell it what service to call for the map.

Edit:
Can you read my comments? Something seems broken...
It helps to visualize both global map and local costmap in RVIZ to see what is actually happening.

Can you post a sceenshot from RVIZ with the map, costmap and the green/blue movement indicators?
However, if your laser reports an obstacle, the Operator will try to avoid it. There is probably little you can do about that from the costmap-side. Maybe you can pre-filter the laser scan?

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1